# Format IP from tcpflow output?

Tags: java, regex

Im using **tcpflow** to log ip address's however the format is not typical.

```
089.108.003.152
```

The above ip address is what **tcpflow** outputs.
How can I format it as a proper ip via regex?

```
89.108.3.152
```

The ip above is an example of desired format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to use regex, the alternative would be:

```
InetAddress.getByName("089.108.003.152").getHostAddress();
```

Comment: Which is more efficient?

Comment: `String.replaceAll()` method will require Pattern compile each time you call it in the accepted answer. That is the relatively expensive part if you are that sensitive to the efficiency. You may want to call `Pattern.compile(regex)` once and reuse it for each occurrence of IP address string for matching. Regarding my answer, since the string is IPv4 by assumption, `InetAddress.getByName()` will not do a lookup to the network. So it will generate the result a bit faster than the accepted answer according to my test with calling each alternative 1 million times. 2153 ms vs 1372 ms respectively.

Answer (score 4):

This will work for you :

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    String s = "089.108.003.152";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=^|\\.)0+", "")); // positive look - behind for beginning of String or a "."
}
```

O/P :

```
89.108.3.152
```

Comment: this regex eats up all zeroes if a byte is 0 and therefore needs improvement. For example, 010.000.000.001 becomes 100...1

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundaries:

```
"089.108.003.152".replaceAll("\\b0+\\B", "")
```